# Sorting associative array elements in PHP

Tags: php, associative-array

i have got an associative array as follows:

```
$data['england']='pound'
$data['america']='dollar'
$data['europe']='euro'
$data['denmark']='krone'
$data['japan']='yen'
```

I want to sort this array and after that i want 'europe' to be the first element in the array. To sort the array, i am using ksort() in php, now how can i get hold of the 'europe' array object so that i can make it the first element and shift all the remaining elements down?

Comment: I suggest using a better data structure

Comment: if you already found `ksort` in the manual, what stopped you from investigating the other `*sort` functions? Also, what is your sorting logic? Just putting Europe first? What about the other elements?

Comment: my sorting logic is that all elements should be sorted by their keys except for 'euro' which shud be at the top!!

Comment: no it doesn't!! it is sorted alphabetically using ksort(). what i dont knw and why i asked this question was to know, how can someone access elements in an associative array without knowing the key. e.g in normal array u can use array[0] to get the first element, array[1] to get the second element, array[2] to get the third element...how can i get the first, second and third etc element when its associative array!!

Comment: $array[0] does not necessarily return the first element. It returns the element with the numeric key 0. That *can but may not be* the element at offset/position 0. if you want to get Europe from that array, use $array['europe']. Please refresh your array knowledge at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution would be to first remove europe from the array and then do the ksort. When the array is sorted you can use the [`array_unshift()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) or [`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)  to add europe as the first element in the array.

An example using merge:

```
<?php
$data['england']='pound';
$data['america']='dollar';
$data['europe']='euro';
$data['denmark']='krone';
$data['japan']='yen';

unset($data['europe']);
ksort($data);
$data = array('europe' => 'euro') + $data;

print_r($data);
?>
```

Usage of the `+` operator will not reindex the array as the merge-operator would.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a callback for sorting:

```
$data = array (
  'england' => 'pound',
  'america' => 'dollar',
  'europe' => 'euro',
  'denmark' => 'krone',
  'japan' => 'yen'
);

uksort($data, function($a, $b) {
  if($a == 'europe') return -1;
  if($b == 'europe') return 1;
  return $a > $b;
});
```